# Rails nesting static routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have several static pages (About, Contact, Help) that are mapped in the `routes.rb` file like this:

```
get 'about', to: 'static#about', as: 'about'
get 'contact', to: 'static#contact', as: 'contact'
get 'help', to: 'static#help', as: 'help'
```

They are accessed in the layout partial, `_footer.html.erb` from this code:

```
<%= link_to "About", 'about_path', :class => '' %>
<%= link_to "Contact", 'contact_path',  :class => '' %>
<%= link_to "Help", 'help_path', :class => '' %>
```

Everything works fine until I click on the footer links while I'm in a nested route like `/users/current/edit` (where I might edit my user-profile).  For example, when I click on the **ABOUT** link at the bottom of the page, I would expect to be taken directly to the static#about route at `about_path`.

However, I am getting an ActionController exception (in development) and a page not found in production.  It's trying to map to `/users/current/about_path`.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Just change <%= link_to "About", about_path, :class => '' %>

Comment: Yup, noob mistake.  Thanks, Thorin.  Been staring at the code too long...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Thorin's answer.  Remove the quotes around the path method call.